# How to invoke a Python script from a PHP webpage?

Tags: php, python

I've just started messing about a bit with Python on my WAMP home web server and although I can run my scripts perfectly well by typing the path into my browser (localhost/myscript.py) etc and the output displays how can I run them from a PHP page?

Specifically, I am (or will be) using a Python script to display dynamic content on the homepage of my homegrown CMS but this preferably needs to be invoked from my index.php, partially so that users do not see *.py or *.cgi extensions and partially because I can write the site header as normal in the PHP and then invoke my Python script to render the 10 most recent posts or something. I am not very experienced in PHP, however, so am not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,
Ilmiont

Comment: And why would you need php to do that? Are you using a framework for your python CMS?

Comment: I mean you  could use exec (http://php.net/function.exec) and get the output the script returned...but then you have to do some parsing and what not. Why not just use PHP for it all?

Comment: I'm not using any framework for my CMS... by 'homegrown' I mean 'from scratch'... I've got a GUI (Tkinter) for me to write posts with and my PHP templates to display the posts in but I need the homepage... ideally, I don't want to direct users to a *.py page. Python is my language, you see, so that is why I am rendering the content using it...

Comment: .htaccess file will remove the extension (.py, .cgi whatever). If your python file is executable then you can run it by simply using include "your file" Hope this will help.

Comment: What? Sorry, I'm lost from your explanation @Moyeen, can you please dumb it down a bit for a n00b to web dev? Thanks. And yh, my Python file is executable.

Answer (score 0):

As your are running apache, you might want to have a look at [the Web Server Gateway Interface or WSGI](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#wsgi)